# Javascript regex preg_replace

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Regex (ported from PHP to Javascript, Node.js) applied on this string:

```
/users/:uid/posts/:pid
/users/:uid
/messages/:mid
```

The strings above, contain arguments (after the ":" symbol) untill the next forward slash, I replace these with a string regex. And eventually it should be like this:

```
/users/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/posts/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)
```

So all the arguments in the routing, should be replaced with a regular expression string. I use the following code to achieve this:

```
var fixedRoute = route[url].replace(/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/, '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)');
```

The output is the same, the strings are not replaced. Can anyone help me with this regex?

Thanks alot

Comment: /messages/:mid should become: /messages/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)

Comment: what is the contents of route[url] ?

Comment: var routes = { 'GET /users/': { 'controller': 'users', 'action': 'get' } the first string 'GET /users/' would be the content of route[url]

Comment: one moment, i'm testing my regex now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) and it's backreference.

So that would become something like 'hihi-foobar'.replace(/foo(bar)/i, $1);
would render 'hihi-bar'.

**UPDATE** (based on comments above):

```
.replace(/:[upm]id/ig, ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+));
```

Comment: I have tried using /g as global modifier but it did not work ... what else could be causing the problem?

Comment: I don't understand with capturing group / back reference.

Comment: you don't need to anymore. Regex from update will replace 'uid', 'pid' and 'mid' with what you want.   You can quickly try this regex over [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and see that it works!

Comment: Thank you for the accept! Do you understand the regex or need extra explanation?